# How to load huge data into array list or any other data structure?

Tags: java, android, performance, sqlite

I have 5000 to 10000 records in an sqlite database and I would like to load it into memory (ArrayList/HashMap etc). Which data structure is the most suitable to load huge amounts of data and access it frequently in android.

Comment: This really comes down to how you access the data, as a `HashMap` would do great for random access but slower for linear access, which is what an `ArrayList` is for. Can you expand on how you're accessing the data?

Comment: If ArrayList holds 10000 records won't it impact performance?

Comment: To help you we'll need more understanding on how your're working with the data. Doing anything affects performance and how you do it affects performance and what you're doing it with also affects performance.

Comment: Accessing list of passenger details frequently and random also..

Comment: Use "limit" in your database when you want to access data (in query in which you get all records), an increase its parameter when its needed, and then load data in your structure again, this way you will not get all data at once but gradually.

Comment: 10000 records is not so much. HashMap or HashSet would be fine. To tell you more, we'd need to know what type of data you want to store and how you want to retrieve it and search through it. The only limit is having enough memory, and finding the information you want may be a little slow also.

Comment: @JonasCz: I will be storing the objects in the values and integer in the key part..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to quickly access 1000's of records randomly and quickly in Android use a `HashMap` it will allow for constant time access of the data, in addition you can use additional data structure objects to create indexes. For example, if you're data is stored in `HashMap<int, Passenger> data` and you need to sort passengers by surname you can use `sqlite` to create a list of Passenger ID's and access the data already loaded into the `data` object. If ordering is not important for an index you can still use an `ArrayList`, a `HashSet` is also good if you're index ID's needs to be guaranteed unique.

Comment: Thanks Got an idea will attempt it.

Comment: If the indices are consecutive and start at 0, a list would be simpler.